# Drawing a rhombus-shaped border to an image

Tags: python

I need to add border to an image, but in rhombus shape, I can easily add rectangular border with the following code, but need some ideas how to draw a rhombus with python wand or PIL. I can flip a rectangle, but the text should fit inside the rhombus. Another idea is to draw four straight lines and connect them. Perhaps some of you already solved that in a better way. Looking for hints how to do it efficiently.

desired shaped:

[image]

```
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from moviepy.editor import *

# -size 320x100 xc:lightblue
with Image(width=320, height=100, background=Color('lightblue')) as image:
    with Drawing() as draw:
        # -font Candice
        draw.font = 'Candice'
        # -pointsize 72
        draw.font_size = 72.0
        draw.push()
        # -fill black
        draw.fill_color = Color('black')
        # -draw "text 28,68 'Anthony'"
        draw.text(28, 68, 'Anthony')
        draw.pop()
        draw.push()
        # -fill white
        draw.fill_color = Color('white')
        # -draw "text 25,65 'Anthony'"
        draw.text(25, 65, 'Anthony')
        draw.pop()
        draw(image)
    # font_shadow.jpg
    image.border(Color('red'), 3,3)
    image.save(filename='font_shadow.jpg')
    #display(image)
```